# RewriteCond not stopping at end.. /example will work... but example/anotherlink doesnt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this might be a no brainer to some, but I am trying to specify some RewriteCond in an .htaccess file and I am failing badly.

Heres what I have :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} employee   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /resources/employee [L,R=301]
```

will redirect fine... but if I include any other rules that include 'employee' like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} employee/another   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ resources/employee/another [L,R=301]
```

It redirects me to the first Rule: /resources/employee

I have tried many variations, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond` uses a regular expression, and searches your value for it. To make sure it only matches whole string, use the `^` and `$`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^employee$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} employee   [NC]
```

will match anything with employee in it, try using some anchoring, like to the beginning and end of filename or similar:

```
# Match everything that starts with /employee, might be followed by a slash and then ends
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/employee/?$   [NC]
```

Comment: yeah, noticed that... how can I stop it at the end of employee and then create another rule for employee/another and end it at another?  Thats my problem.  Right now, its redirecting all requests with employee in path to the same place.